# SQL Server Int primary key and Guid

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I’ve recently moved companies and they do something in SQL Server that I have not seen before. I am used to using a primary key column as an int that increments on inserts, very occasionally I've seen the use of guids but here they use both, see below.

```
PrimaryID | GUID | RestOfColumns
```

I can't get my head round why? When asking this question they told me it was another layer of protection against SQL injection. In stored procedures they are using the guid to find the primary key ID and then using the id anyway, I personally cannot see the benefit?

My questions are:

- Is there any security risk to exposing the primary key in code?
- Are there any benefits to using the guid to get the primary key?

**EDIT:**

An example of the usage (pseudo code):

1. I need a contact.
2. Retrieve Contact Guid from QueryString.
3. Call SQL Server stored procedure to get contact.
4. In stored procedure: find the id in the contact table based on the guid.
5. Use the id to get relevant values in others tables using the id as a foreign key.
6. Return data.

Comment: "another layer of protection against sql injection"??? Seriously?? Sounds like somebody who doesn't know why this is being done using a couple buzzwords to make it sound super cool. If they parameterize their sql there is no risk of sql injection. That happens when you directly execute parameter values either in pass through sql or dynamic sql. This all seems a bit overkill to me but the actual implementation is not clear from your post.

Comment: I agree with @SeanLange, sounds like someone who read a couple of articles, put two and two together, and came up with five.

Comment: Somehting else mentioned to me was that using INT Ids to search in sql is quicker but its safer to expose the guid in the logic. So the "safer" guid is used to get the "quicker" id in sql. This might be my lack of sql knowledge but this doenst seem right. Im try to gather enough information so I can persuade them to start using a more standardized practise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If somebody looks at your website's html source, they might see that they are submitting a form and passing their ID which is "1003".    So from there, they could construct a form that passes the ID of "1002" and see somebody else's data.   It's not exactly "SQL Injection", it's more like parameter-guessing.

But if they see their ID is a GUID, which just looks like random characters, they'd have a much harder time guessing what other valid IDs might be in your system.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, but can you see any point in using the guid as well as an int id?

Comment: Well the point would be that you use the GUID from the front end, for security, and then you use the INT ID as the PK for joins to other tables, since joins on INTs will perform faster than joins on GUIDs.

Comment: Very plausible explanation and much more helpful than the judgmental comments from others.

Answer (score 0):

The main benefit would be:  We already have a bunch of code that uses PrimaryID, including ORM code that maps PrimaryID as the primary key column.  The only other reason I can see to keep PrimaryID is for human readability.

Also, I should let you know that GUID doesn't always protect you from data scraping.  You could very well be using a database that generates GUIDs in a predictable pattern (sequential or otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to have a int primary key and a separate Guid is for replication. Replication requires you specify a [ROWGUIDCOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) which must be of type `uniqueidentifier`.

This is done because you may be generating data on multiple servers and merging the data together during the replication process. To do that you need a ID that will be unique to the row even if the rows are generated across two servers that have no communication.