# Are there problems with using GUID's as indexed fields in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, guid

I've read a lot of articles that mention that using a guid as a clustered indexed (or primary key) in SQL Server could cause performance issues.

However, due to some design decisions, I really do need a field with `GUID` in it for each line of one table.

If I define the primary key of that table as an autoincrement integer, and add the `GUID` as a normal column which is indexed, will I have performance issues similar to having the `GUID` as the primary key?

Edit: As a side note, I know that GUID as a primary key is a bad idea, I am asking if I will have performance issues if I set it as an indexed (non clustered) field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the best practices for using a GUID as a primary key, specifically regarding performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938044/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-a-guid-as-a-primary-key-specifically-rega)

Comment: I also read many articles like that. But then i tried to figure out myself by creating a t-sql loop and leaving overnight. To my surprise, the page load time was almost same as before except for the first req after build. To be precise there were 4.5 lakhs entries in the db

Comment: when you say as before, you mean that when you changed the primary key to autoincrement int, and left a field as indexed guid, you got the same results as when you had guid as a primary key?

Comment: The GUID is a potential performance issue ***only and only when*** used as the **clustering index** on the table

Comment: no. I never changed the table structure. Before means that table had around 10 entries. After means that table had 4.5 lakh entries. Both the times guid was pk as well as clustering key.

Comment: @RachitGupta: what's important is the question whether that columns is the **clustered index** on that table (whether or not it's the PK is irrelevant)

Comment: If you use a guid as a primary key, your data file will be more "fragemented", because a guid is a random value. When you add a new row in your table, the row is added randomly in the file. In your clustered index, you could add other fields, and add your guid at last.

Comment: Another SO question that might be relevant:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655010/sql-server-int-primary-key-and-guid

Comment: so if I use a guid field but I just have it as indexed, not a cluster index, I shouldn't have performance problems?

Comment: @RomEh that isn't quite correct. You can have a guid as a primary key with no issue. The fragmentation is when the guid is your clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

What type of index you want to use for GUID field? Clustered? Unique? If just unique, then GUID will not be differ from any other unique field. You can use it without doubt.
In case of clustered index it will affect performance. You can use [Sequential GUID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx). It can solve some performance issues. Generating of GUID on the client-side also can improve performance.

Comment: The guid is not created by the sql server. Basically the guid is created by an android application, it is sent along with the other data to the sql server, and then requests back the id that the sql server assigned to it, I was thinking of making it indexed to speed up the sql server search to locate the id that it assigned to it